# Cumulative sum that resets after a threshold has been exceeded

Tags: pyspark

I'm relatively new with pyspark and python in general. This is probably trivial but I can't quite get it.

I've got a dataset that contains an ID, a DATE column, and a column X that contains floats. What I'd like to do is, over the ID and ordered by DATE, calculate the running total of X. When that running total exceeds a value Y, then restart the total. An example is below, where Y = 20:

```
|ID |DATE        | X   | cumsum_X |
-----------------------------------
|  1|  2017-03-01|   10|        10|
|  1|  2017-03-02|   12|        22|
|  1|  2017-03-03|    5|         5|
|  1|  2017-03-04|   10|        15|
|  2|  2015-01-01|    6|         6|
|  2|  2015-01-03|    7|        13|
```

I've been able to calculate the cumulative sum over the group and ordered properly with the code below, but I'm not sure how to modify it to get the reseting behavior that I want.

```py
win =(Window(partitionBy('ID').over('DATE'))
      .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))

df = df.withColumn('cumsum_x', F.Sum('X').over(win))
```

Comment: Sounds like a difficult task for a distributed system: the last cumulative value for each ID can be changed by each of the other values for that ID.

Comment: Perhaps you can make an ordered list of X values and then compute the cumsum_X per row

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses a little trick to reset the cumulative sum.

First, I compute the running sum for each ID. Afterwards, I group the resulting sums into bins that depend on the reset value. Finally, I use the original IDs and the intra-ID bins to compute the reset cumulative sums.

**Code:**

```
    # imports
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col
    import pyspark.sql.functions as F
    from pyspark.sql.window import Window
    
    
    # value for resetting cummulative sum
    reset_value = 20
    
    # dummy DataFrame
    df = spark.createDataFrame([
      [1, 1, 10],
      [1, 2, 12],
      [1, 3, 5],
      [1, 4, 10],
      [2, 1, 6],
      [2, 3, 7]
    ], schema=["id", "t", "x"])
    
    # windows
    w1 = Window().partitionBy("id").orderBy("t")
    w2 = Window().partitionBy("id", "cumsum_group").orderBy("t").rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
    
    # reset AFTER reset value is reached
    df2 = (df
           .withColumn("cumsum_x", F.sum("x").over(w1.rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)))
           .withColumn("cumsum_group", (col("cumsum_x") / reset_value).cast("int"))
           .withColumn("cumsum_x_reset", F.sum("x").over(w2))
          )
    
    # reset BEFORE reset value is reached
    df3 = (df
           .withColumn("cumsum_x", F.sum("x").over(w1.rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)))
           .withColumn("cumsum_group", (col("cumsum_x") / reset_value).cast("int"))
           .withColumn("cumsum_group", F.lag("cumsum_group").over(w1))
           .withColumn("cumsum_group", F.when(col("cumsum_group").isNull(), 0).otherwise(col("cumsum_group")))
           .withColumn("cumsum_x_reset", F.sum("x").over(w2))
          )
```

**Output:**

```
+---+---+---+
| id|  t|  x|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  1| 10|
|  1|  2| 12|
|  1|  3|  5|
|  1|  4| 10|
|  2|  1|  6|
|  2|  3|  7|
+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+--------+------------+--------------+
| id|  t|  x|cumsum_x|cumsum_group|cumsum_x_reset|
+---+---+---+--------+------------+--------------+
|  1|  1| 10|      10|           0|            10|
|  1|  2| 12|      22|           1|            12|
|  1|  3|  5|      27|           1|            17|
|  1|  4| 10|      37|           1|            27|
|  2|  1|  6|       6|           0|             6|
|  2|  3|  7|      13|           0|            13|
+---+---+---+--------+------------+--------------+

+---+---+---+--------+------------+--------------+
| id|  t|  x|cumsum_x|cumsum_group|cumsum_x_reset|
+---+---+---+--------+------------+--------------+
|  1|  1| 10|      10|           0|            10|
|  1|  2| 12|      22|           0|            22|
|  1|  3|  5|      27|           1|             5|
|  1|  4| 10|      37|           1|            15|
|  2|  1|  6|       6|           0|             6|
|  2|  3|  7|      13|           0|            13|
+---+---+---+--------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: hey I know this is old, but thank you so much for this solution. Has helped me tremendously!